# How to make a border fit around a JLabel

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I would like to make my JLabel have a border which fits around the text. I have tried using ints to resize but that doesn't work. Can anyone help?
Here is my Java code:

```
package first;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TopLevelWindow {
    static int hgap=5;
    static int vgap=5;

        private static void createWindow() {
            //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
            JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Welcome Child",SwingConstants.CENTER);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
            textLabel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            textLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));
            //Display the window.
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {  createWindow();  }
}
```

I would want it to look like the text box in this: 
http://www.bogleech.com/halloween/undertale-grillbys.png 
is that possible in java?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if you set your JLabel’s size to 300×300, its border will be around that rectangle.

Instead, leave the JLabel’s size alone, and place it inside a panel with a centering layout, then place the border on that panel:

```
JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Welcome Child",SwingConstants.CENTER);
textLabel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
textLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));

JPanel textPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
textPanel.add(textLabel);
textPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

frame.getContentPane().add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the effect from the screen you should set the vertical alignment to `NORTH` and use CompoundBorder consisting of white outer border and inner invisible border which looks like the margin. Try this piece of code:

```
JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Test test test test test test test...");
textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
textLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
textLabel.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 30));

// sets the text to the upper left corner
textLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.NORTH);

textLabel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder( // sets two borders
BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, Color.WHITE), // outer border
BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10))); // inner invisible border as the margin
```

Comment: Could you describe what you wanted to achieve? Do you want the border to "touch" the text from up, down, left and right?

Comment: I have now edited my post to include a link to a picture of a text box similar to what I wanted, if that would be more useful for you

Comment: @ChrisHowes so you want the text to start in left upper corner?

Comment: Yes and I would like the label's border to just fit around the text, like in the picture

Comment: @ChrisHowes I have edited my answer. Check it out and accept it as the correct one if it helps. Cheers!